# Why would you prefer employer to pay all non-taxable benefits and you pay for the benefits that are taxable if your employer pays them?

Tags: ontario, benefits

[*Tax Planning for You and Your Family 2019*](https://home.kpmg/ca/en/home/insights/2018/11/tax-planning-for-you-and-your-family-2019.html) by KPMG. p 153.

> #### 10.1.1 Non-taxable employment benefits
>
> Certain employment benefits are not taxable, even though many of them are
>   deductible expenses to the employer. The government is thus offering an
>   incentive to employers to provide these benefits, since the after-tax returns
>   are greater than straight salary. Non-taxable benefits include:
>
> • Contributions to a registered pension plan (the pension is taxable
>   when received—see 3.5.1)
>   • Contributions to a group sickness or accident insurance plan
>   • Contributions to a “private health services plan”, such as those
>   covering drugs, medical expenses and hospital charges not covered
>   by public health insurance, and dental fees (except for Quebec
>   purposes—see 17.10.2)

p 154 [Let me know if you want me list whole page of bullets]

> • All or a portion of the cost of free or subsidized school services for your
>   children (for example, if the services are provided in a remote area)
>   • Contributions to a supplementary unemployment benefit plan

p 155. I omit six benefits at page top.

> Note that where your employer deducts its contributions to a sickness
>   or accident insurance plan, a disability insurance plan or an income
>   maintenance insurance plan, any benefits you receive from the insurance
>   will be taxable (but reduced by your own premium payments to the plan).
>
> Ask your employer to make use of the nontaxable
>   benefits outlined above as much as
>   possible. If you have an employment benefit
>   package where you and the employer share the
>   costs, try to have the cost-sharing reallocated so your employer pays for
>   all the **non-taxable** benefits and you pay for the benefits that are **taxable** if
>   your employer pays them. In many cases, without changing the cost to your
>   employer, you can reduce your tax burden this way.

Don't you want reverse? Isn't **non-taxable** supposed to be swapped with *taxable** in that sentence?

Isn't employer supposed to pay for all TAXABLE benefits so that you aren't taxed? Wouldn't you prefer paying all NON-TAXABLE benefits because you don't pay tax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't employer supposed to pay for all TAXABLE benefits so that you aren't taxed? Wouldn't you prefer paying all NON-TAXABLE benefits because you don't pay tax?

No, because you are misunderstanding exactly what **taxable benefits** means: possibly because in the above sentence you're only emphasising the *taxable* bit and perhaps overlooking the *benefits* bit).

A **taxable benefit** is something an employer provides on which you need to pay tax ***as though they had given you the equivalent value of that benefit in cash as part of your salary***. On the other hand, a **non-taxable benefit** is one where you ***don't*** need to pay tax (in effect, the equivalent value is deducted from your salary *before* it assessed for taxes).

***Note**: I'm neither a Canadian, nor an accountant. The examples below may not be 100% accurate and are for illustrative purposes only. They only consider federal taxes, based on the figures from [Canadian income tax rates for individuals - current and previous years](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/frequently-asked-questions-individuals/canadian-income-tax-rates-individuals-current-previous-years.html). Specifically, that for 2019 the tax-rate on taxable-income of up to just shy of $48k is 15%. To keep figures simple, I've also taken the **basic personal amount** (the amount you can earn before tax) to be $12k (instead of $12,069 for 2019).*

Suppose you earn $48,000 per year. Your employer offers you an extra $500 per month as either **(a)** a *non-taxable benefit* (e.g. contribution to an appropriate pension plan); **(b)** a *taxable benefit* (perhaps a company car<sup>**1**</sup>); or **(c)** extra cash in your pay-packet.

**Case A: Non-Taxable Benefit**

```
Gross income:            48,000
Basic personal amount:   12,000-
                        -------
Taxable income:          36,000
Tax payable:              5,400-    (15% of 36,000)
                        -------
Post-tax income:         30,600
Non-taxable income:       6,000
                        -------
Total income:           $36,600
```

**Case B: Taxable Benefit**

```
Gross income:            48,000
Taxable benefit:          6,000
Basic personal amount:   12,000-
                        -------
Taxable income:          42,000
Tax payable:              6,300-    (15% of 42,000)
                        -------
Post-tax income:         35,700
                        -------
Total income:           $35,700
```

**Case C: Salary Increase**

```
Gross income:            54,000     (48,000 + 12x500)
Basic personal amount:   12,000-
                        -------
Taxable income:          42,000
Tax payable:              6,300     (15% of 42,000)
                        -------
Post-tax income:         35,700
                        -------
Total income:           $35,700
```

As you can see, having the employer pay for a ***non-taxable benefit*** leaves you **$900 per year** better off, compared to having them pay for a ***taxable benefit*** (or simply giving you the cash). This figure is (of course?) 15% of the $6,000 value of the benefit/raise.

In simplistic terms<sup>**2**</sup>, if *you* were to pay for *non-taxable benefits*, you would be doing so out of *already-taxed-money*, whereas your employer does so out of *pre-tax money* (thus reducing the amount you *do* pay tax on).

---

<sup>**1**</sup> A company car might not be the perfect example (in the UK the tax situation on them can be, I believe, complicated). If necessary, substitute anything that does not fall into the *non-taxable* category.

<sup>**2**</sup> Depending on how similar (or not) the Canadian system is to the UK's, it's possible/probable that you can claim back the tax already paid on non-taxable expenditure.